# How do I load a xib file from my cocoapod?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

My xib files are in the Assets folder of my Pod like this.

```
s.resources = 'Pod/Assets'
```

The xib files show up in my workspace in the `Development Pods` group of the cocoa pod.  I'm trying to access the xib like this.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LabeledTextFieldView" owner:self options:nil];
```

But I get the following crash

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/jeff.wolski/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/775EB653-519B-4FCF-8CD9-92311E205598/LT-Components-iOS.app> (loaded)' with name 'LabeledTextFieldView''
```

Why is the xib file not found in the bundle?

Comment: Have you figured out why? I'm having a similar problem...

Comment: the s.resources folder will not automatically recurse to subdirectories. I had to specify the full relative path to the xib files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `s.resources` folder will not automatically recurse to subdirectories. I had to specify the full relative path to the xib files.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that your resource file is not being included in the `mainBundle` you should look at some of the [`NSBundle` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and use something like `bundleForClass:` to get the correct bundle to load the `xib` from. The output of `[NSBundle allBundles` may also be informative.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `s.resources` with in your library podspec. Add `s.resources = 'FOLDER_INCLUDES_XIB_FILES/*.xib'`. And to initiate your class with xib file

**Objective-C**

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:self.classForCoder];
UINib *nib = [[bundle loadNibNamed:@"YOUR_XIB_FILE_NAME" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
```

**Swift 3** and **Swift 4**

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: self.classForCoder())
return bundle.loadNibNamed("YOUR_XIB_FILE_NAME", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to all all nibs in {podName}.podspec

```
s.resource_bundles = {
'{podName}' => ['{podName}/Classes/*.xib']
```

}

and when you need to declare new view

```
NSBundle *podBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[viewController class]];
id data = [podBundle URLForResource:@"{podName}" withExtension:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:data];
viewController *view = [[viewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"viewController" bundle:bundle];
```

replace {podName} to your project name

Answer (score 2):

I run to this issue, 
[image]

and refer to Keith Smiley's answer, I go to docs have a look:

I finnally change the bundle init method from `Class` like this:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[EBBannerView class]];
NSArray *banners = [bundle loadNibNamed:@"EBBannerView" owner:nil options:nil];
```

Then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In here you need to add this into your pod spec.

```
 s.resources = "YourProjectName/*.xib"
 s.resource_bundles = {
   'YourProjectName' => [
       'Pod/**/*.xib'
   ]
 }
```

Then retrieve the xib file from the bundle like this:-

```
 let podBundle = Bundle(for:YourClassName.self)
    if let bundleURL = podBundle.url(forResource: "YourProjectName", withExtension: "bundle") {
        if let bundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL) {
            let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "nibFileName", bundle: bundle)
            navigationTableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "nibFileReuseIdentifierName")
        } else {
            assertionFailure("Could not load the bundle")
        }
    } else {
        assertionFailure("Could not create a path to the bundle")
    }
```