# Could not load NIB in bundle - own framework in pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have developed a framework and add it into pod so the dev can install it using the pod, it is done.
but when the developer is trying to load a controller they are getting this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)' with name 'XViewController''

Some help found on google/stackoverflow but didn't work
Bundle code is

```
static var framework: Bundle? {
        let currentBundle = Bundle.init(for: XViewController.self)
        if let path = currentBundle.path(forResource: "Resources", ofType: "bundle") {
            return Bundle(path: path)
        }
        return currentBundle
}
```

The pod contains a `.framework` file only

podspec file is

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name           = 'XXSDK'
  s.version        = '1.0.1'
  s.summary        = 'A tool to enforce Swift style and conventions.'
  s.homepage       = 'https://example.com/sdkportal/'
  s.license        = { :type => 'MIT' }
  s.author         = { 'XXX' => 'abc@gmail.com' }
s.source            = { :http => 'fakeurl/XXSDKframework.zip' }
    s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'
    s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'XXSDK.framework'
  s.dependency "RealmSwift"
  s.dependency "Alamofire"
  s.dependency "MBProgressHUD"
end
```

Everything is working fine if I use `.framework` by just inserting `XXSDK.framework` file, but if I use pod it is causing the above problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your pod contain a NIB named XViewController?

Comment: pod contain .framework file only. everything is under that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433110/how-do-i-load-a-xib-file-from-my-cocoapod

Comment: Check the target membership of XViewController. If it's another target than your pod target it won't find it.