# *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, frameworks, xib

I want to load view controller from framework to my app and when I do that it break with below error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/npiparav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrueLayer-cazpxrhsoxmpwrcknkdhujhcrkdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TLList/TLList.framework> (loaded)' with name 'PokemonListView''
```

I have PokemonListView with xib in my LList framework but I could not load into my project.

I have also tried below code, It does not work either.

```
public init() {
        let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "org.cocoapods.id")
        super.init(nibName: "PokemonListView", bundle: bundle)
        
    }
```

[image: Framework project bundle resources]

[image: once I add framework as pod to my project]

Comment: Are you sure that the nib exists in that bundle? And are you sure it has that exact name?

Comment: Another extra check: if it's a bundle made by you, double check that the nib is actually included in the bundle and Copy bundle resources is checked for this bundle, also the nib is included in the target. Just to eliminate any such issues.

Comment: It exist in my framework but when I add my framework as pod to my project I do not see xib under copy bundle resources. I am adding screenshots

Comment: Ok, I remember trying to include some nibs in a Pod and that was quite a journey. If I remember correctly there is some non-intuitive stuff you have to do. I'll try to find what I've done and try and help you. I vaguely remember that I ended up creating a separate bundle included in my pod which contained the nib files.

Comment: Also, check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433110/how-do-i-load-a-xib-file-from-my-cocoapod It might work to just setup the resources properly.

Comment: @VladRusu ok let me check this seems need to add in pod spec file to add xib and other types of files