# Framework iOS-XIB can't load NIB in package

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

My application is getting crashed when i try to access the nib files which is a part of my framework bundle. This is the code i am using to access the view controllers XIB file.

below is the code that i used in the framework

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public class AdsManager {
public static let shared = AdsManager()

public func showTest(in vc: UIViewController) {
    let bundel = Bundle.init(for: TestViewController.self)
    let testVc = TestViewController(nibName: "TestViewController", bundle: bundel)
    vc.present(testVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

and in the demo project

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }

 @IBAction func actTest(_ sender: Any) {
    AdsManager.shared.showTest(in: self)
 }

}
```

and the problem encountered
[image]

[image]

and in pod folder

Comment: Is the XIB part of the framework? Does it get compiled within the framework bundle?

Comment: @Cristik XIB is part of the framework, did i miss any setup?

Comment: Are you integrating the framework via CocoaPods? From the screenshot you just added seems so, in that case check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433110/how-do-i-load-a-xib-file-from-my-cocoapod

Comment: @Cristik I have framework integration through CocoaPods, it hasn't solved my problem yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem,
push the xib file to the resource folder

```
spec.resources     = "MobileAds/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,storyboard,xib,xcassets}"
```